# How to get the index of an array of sessions? - cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, session, cakephp

Friends, I have an array where I need to get the index dynamically to be able to delete the specific session.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcUhY.png)

I tried to link the delete button like this in cart.ctp:

```
   <html>
  <body>
    <!--Main layout-->
    <main class="mt-1 pt-1">
      <div class="container wow fadeIn">

        <!-- Heading -->

        <div class="row">
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-md-8 mb-4">

            <!--Card-->
            <div class="card">

              <?php foreach($this->Session->read('cart') as $cart): ?>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">product</th>
                          <th scope="col">PREÇO</th>
                          <th scope="col">Qte</th>
                          <th scope="col">SUBTOTAL</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row">
                            <?= $cart->has('product') ? $this->Html->link($cart->product->nome_product, ['controller' => 'products', 'action' => '/', $cart->product->id]) : '' ?>
                          </th>
                          <td>
                            <strong>R$ <?php echo number_format($cart->product->price, 2, ',', '') ?></strong>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <strong><?php echo $cart->quantity; ?> un.</strong>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <strong>
                              R$ <?php 
                              $sub = ($cart->product->preco * $cart->quantidade);
                              echo number_format($sub, 2, ',', '');
                              ?>
                            </strong>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <hr width="40%">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 


            <div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-9">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-1 mt-3">


             </div>
             <div class="col-md-1 mt-3">
              <?= $this->Html->link(__('Remove'), ['action' => 'remove', $cart->index]); ?>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
          </div>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <br>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card-->

      </div>
      <!--Grid column-->

      <!--Grid column-->
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">


        <!-- Promo code -->
        <form class="card p-2">

          <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

      </div>
      <!--Grid row-->

    </div>
  </main>
  <!--Main layout-->

</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to pass the $cart->index variable to the method.

```
public function remove($index = mull) {
.
$cart = $this->request->session();
$cart->delete->("cart.$index");
.
```

But debugging ($cart->index) the value is null.

Can you help me get the session value index? (0,1,2..)

Appreciate!

Comment: First, you should include any relevant details directly in the question. Making people click links to find the information greatly reduces the number of people who will make the effort to help you.  Second, it looks like you may have cut important information off the top of your data; the column counting from 0 has no heading?

Comment: You're also going to need to include a little more code around the `link` link. There's probably something like a `foreach` that we'll need to see.

Comment: I posted all the code. Thanks for any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "index" appears to not be a part of the records you have saved in your session, but rather just the array index. Your loop needs to be:

```
foreach($this->Session->read('cart') as $index => $cart):
```

And your link:

```
$this->Html->link(__('Remove'), ['action' => 'remove', $index]);
```